# Coinigy v2 API - How to call Trade History API with StartDate and EndDate Parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

With Reference to https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/docs/, trying to call

`/private/exchanges/{exchCode}/markets/{baseCurrCode}/{quoteCurrCode}/trades/history`

This api has following parameters:

1. exchCode : URL Parameter
2. baseCurrCode : URL Parameter
3. quoteCurrCode : URL Parameter
4. StartDate : DateTime / Query Parameter
5. EndDate : DateTime / Query Parameter

Based on these details following is final url generated:

https://api.coinigy.com/api/v2/private/exchanges/BITS/markets/BTC/USD/Trades/history?StartDate=2008-8-01T12:30:00&EndDate=2018-9-20T12:30:00

and End point generated for signature is

`/api/v2/private/exchanges/BITS/markets/BTC/USD/Trades/history?StartDate=2008-8-01T12:30:00&EndDate=2018-9-20T12:30:00`

But, this is giving always Unauthorized Reply.

What could be reason for this ?

Comment: did you generate your Authentication headers?

Comment: Yes.
All other APIs are working fine. I am having issue only with APIs where Query Parameters need to provided.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `?StartDate=2008-8-01T12:30:00&EndDate=2018-9-20T12:30:00` from your generated endpoint included in the `X-API-SIGN` header generation

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons I can think of that this might be happening off the top of my head:

1. You are not using a key with sufficient access (this endpoint requires a CRYPTOFEED subscription). If you're not sure, check with support or see if the api key management interface offers an indicator of what type of permissions it has
2. As @Ahmed said, the signature should not include parameters in it, just the endpoint itself. Also, for the times, put a 'Z' at the end to specify UTC time

Comment: I believe #2 is now incorrect. The signature should require URL encoded params. See docs for example